# How can i call a method from library to C# console

Tags: c#, methods, class-library

i created a method in a new library 
this is my code

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static bool ISprime(int prime)
        {

            if (prime < 2)
                return false;
            else if (prime == 2)
                return true;
            else
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < prime; i++)
                {
                    if (prime % i == 0)
                        return false;
                    else
                        return true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. how can i call that method in my console " program.cs "
2. i got an error that said " Error 2   'ClassLibrary1.Class1.ISprime(int)': not all code paths return a value"

what does that mean ?

sorry i'm a new programmer.

Comment: Do you really need that `for loop` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Do we really need to find primes? ;p

Comment: @V4 .. yes, the method must make sure it has two divisors ONLY--1 and itself, and no others

Comment: @leppie sorry what i meant was it would return a value in the first iteration itself so why for loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) call the method by doing the following:

```
ClassLibrary1.Class1.ISprime(123);
```

or

```
Class1.ISprime(123);  // make sure to reference ClassLibrary1 at the top of your class
```

2.) You need to return some value at the very end of the method.  I also changed some of the logic:

```
public static bool ISprime(int prime)
{
    if (prime == 1) 
        return false;
    if (prime == 2) 
        return true;

    for (int i = 2; i < Math.Sqrt(prime); ++i)  {
        if (prime % i == 0) 
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

3.) Answering comment about what's different from the logic.  Try running this and you'll see the differences.

```
    for (int n = -10; n < 10; n++)
    {
        if (Class1.IsPrimeCorrect(n) != Class1.IsPrimeIncorrect(n))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the different between them ? .. when i said prime < 2 means even 0 or -1 will give false then we start from 2 .. the problem for that error was i didnt add reference from solution , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Move the `return true` to after the `for` loop.

Try understand why I say that :)

Comment: That explains the error message, now to help with the calling part X-)

Comment: true, but that does not answer the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a compilation error and unrelated to calling it from another program. Basically , through all the if's and the else's, there is a path of execution that does not return a value from the function.

While you can  add a `return true` at the end of your method to satisfy the 
compiler, your logic is also flawed because in the inner (in the loop) else, you are returning true, eventhough it might actually not turn out to be prime. Move the `return true` outside the loop and remove the else part in the loop.

To call this from another assembly / program, you have to reference this assembly and call the method. You may add a using statement too.

Comment: that error gone when i did what you said .. but how can reference it ? sorry but i'm a new .. >> i know how to reference in IsItPrime( ref x) other thing i don;t know .. thanx

Comment: @AbdulrahmanBinFahad - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx