# How can i call this method .. + check if my method is correct or not 

Tags: c#, arrays, console

last night i asked this question .. 
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389870/how-can-i-call-a-method-from-library-to-c-sharp-console)
and members answered me (thanks) 
i have another method that make me like i have problem with it ..

i'll put 2 methods .. second one is what i ask about ..

```
 public static bool ISprime(int prime)
    {

            if (prime < 2 )
                return false;
            else if (prime == 2)
                return true;
            else
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < prime; i++)
                {
                    if (prime % i == 0)
                        return false;
                }

                return true;
            }            
    }
     // second method
    public static int[] GeneratePrimes(int[] n)
    {
        int[] array = new int[n.Length];
        int PrimeLength =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (ISprime(array[i]))
                PrimeLength++;
        }

        int[] arprime = new int[PrimeLength];

        for (int i = 0, j=0; i< PrimeLength; i++)
        {
            if (ISprime(i))
                arprime[j++] = i;
        }
        return arprime;
    }
```

1. GeneratePrimes is this method correct .. i want to put all prime numbers in an array called arprime ..
2. in assembly/program how can i pass a number .. that user type like `Console.ReadLine()`

thank you

Comment: Can you explain what should do your second method? What I see now, is that you have an array of length n.Length filled with zeros. And in the next cycle you are checking each of this elemen (zero) by calling ISprime()

Comment: `      Create a method called "GeneratePrimes"  
         IN: size of array,n     
         OUT: array filled with first n primes
        
         Create an array of size specified & fill with primes
`  that what i need from second method ..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your method will work, but in answer to the second part of your question:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
int n = Convert.ToInt32(s);
int[] arprimes = GeneratePrimes(n);
```

Probably best to put the convert bit in a try, as the user could enter something that is not a number.

EDIT: Actually, I would change the method to be GeneratePrimes(int n) instead of GeneratePrimes(int[] n) - you do not need to pass an array of numbers, just the number as it returns an array.

Another edit: here is your method changed so that you are passing an int instead of an array of ints. Still not sure that the method will actually work though.

```
public static int[] GeneratePrimes(int n)
{
    int[] array = new int[n];
    int PrimeLength =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (ISprime(array[i]))
            PrimeLength++;
    }

    int[] arprime = new int[PrimeLength];

    for (int i = 0, j=0; i< PrimeLength; i++)
    {
        if (ISprime(i))
            arprime[j++] = i;
    }
    return arprime;
}
```

and here is what you want as your main method

```
public static void Main(I cannot remember what goes here!)
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(s);
    int[] arprimes = GeneratePrimes(n);
    string output = "";
    for (i=0; i<arprimes.Length;i++)
    {
        output += arprimes[i].ToString() + ", ";
    }
    output = output.Remove(output.Length - 3, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: use `int.TryParse` instead of try catch

Comment: so how can i call it in assembly ? `string s = Console.ReadLine();
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(s);
            int[] arprimes = new int[n];

            Console.WriteLine(ClassLibrary1.Class1.GeneratePrimes(****));` in stars what can i put?

Comment: I do not think it will work as you expect it to like that. The WriteLine will be expecting a string. You also need to call the method using `int[] arprimes = ClassLibrary1.Class1.GeneratePrimes(n);` to create the array.

Comment: thanx theWaxMann .. how can i change my method ?

Comment: I have changed my answer, it was easier than putting it in a comment.

Comment: What goes 'here' is: string[] args! :D

Comment: i got 2 errors `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.GeneratePrimes(int[])' has some invalid argument` ... second one `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'int[]'` all of them in line 16 which ` int[] arprimes = ClassLibrary1.Class1.GeneratePrimes(n);`

Comment: That will be because your method is still `GeneratePrimes(int[] n)` You need to change that to `GeneratePrimes(int n)` getting rid of the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to have all primes from 1 to n, you need to have something like this:

```
int[] GeneratePrimes(int n)
{
   List<int> primes = new List<int>();
   for (int i=1; i<=n i++)
   {
      if (IsPrime(i))
      {
         primes.Add(i);
      }
   }

   return primes.ToArray();
}
```

But this algorythm isn't effective. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes Also there are another sieves, that even more effective.

**Upd.** If you need first n primes, then you need to do something like this:

```
int[] GeneratePrimes(int n)
{
   List<int> primes = new List<int>();

   while (primes.Length < n)
   {
      if (IsPrime(i))
      {
         primes.Add(i);
      }
   }

   return primes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thanx Archeg .. that link which u gave me helped me to arrange my method .. but what i want to do is `reate a method called "GeneratePrimes"  
         IN: size of array,n     
         OUT: array filled with first n primes
        
         Create an array of size specified & fill with primes`

Comment: what about if i change List to array ? is that will be fit ?

Comment: No, as you cannot know how many primes do you need to generate

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, My understanding is that `GeneratePrimes()` will return an array which has only the prime numbers from the array supplied as parameter.

Your method will not work because, `if (ISprime(array[i]))` will always fail as '`array`' is not having any values assigned to it. You have to use `if (ISprime(n[i]))` instead.

However you can also avoid the two loops doing the same task. Following code might help you:

```
public static int[] GeneratePrimes(int[] n)
{
   List<int> primeList = new List<int>();
   for (int i=0; i<n.Length; i++)
   {
      if(isprime(n[i]))
        primeList.Add(n[i]);
   }

   return primeList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thnx .. but how can i call it from assembly ? like `classlibrary.class1.generatePrimes(**what can we put here**);`

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1:
What you can do is :

```
enter code here

public static int[] GeneratePrimes(int[] n)     
{         
     int[] array = new int[n.Length];  
     int[] arprime = new int[n.Length];    

     int PrimeLength =0;  
     int j=0;       
     for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)          
     {             if (ISprime(array[i]))  
                   {
                         PrimeLength++;  
                         arprime[j++]=array[i];
                   }          
      }
      Array.Resize(ref arprime, PrimeLength);
      return arprime;
```

}

Ans 2:

Include that assembly in namespace

AssemblyName.ClassName.MethodName(Int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())); //For passing integer data otherwize dont cast

Comment: i got 2 errors :( if i type that `string s = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(ClassLibrary1.Class1.GeneratePrimes(int.Parse(s)));`  `** Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'int[]' **` and `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.GeneratePrimes(int[])' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: GeneratePrimes method takes an array of integer not a single integer. Pass a complete array in method while calling it.