# How to access jar file through Xamarin Forms

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, jar

I have a Xamarin project and an android bindings library that has a jar file attached. How can I call a function from the jar library. For example, so that when a button is pressed, a function from the library is called.

Sample project:
[image: sample project]

Comment: Does this answer your question? - [How can i call a method from library to C# console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389870/how-can-i-call-a-method-from-library-to-c-sharp-console).

Comment: the binding library is supposed to expose the methods from the Java library to your C# code

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can check document [Binding a .JAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar).

The Android community offers many Java libraries that you may want to use in your app. These Java libraries are often packaged in `.JAR` (Java Archive) format, but you can package a `.JAR` it in a Java Bindings Library so that its functionality is available to Xamarin.Android apps. The purpose of the Java Bindings library is to make the APIs in the `.JAR` file available to C# code through automatically-generated code wrappers.

Xamarin tooling can generate a Bindings Library from one or more input .JAR files. The Bindings Library (.DLL assembly) contains the following:

- The contents of the original .JAR file(s).
- Managed Callable Wrappers (MCW), which are C# types that wrap
  corresponding Java types within the .JAR file(s).

The generated MCW code uses JNI (Java Native Interface) to forward your API calls to the underlying .JAR file. You can create bindings libraries for any .JAR file that was originally targeted to be used with Android (note that Xamarin tooling does not currently support the binding of non-Android Java libraries). You can also elect to build the Bindings Library without including the contents of the .JAR file so that the DLL has a dependency on the .JAR at runtime.

For more information, you can check: [Binding a Java Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/) .